# Buttons pressed in a certain order SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode

I have buttons on the screen each with a different number and tag(1-12). I want to make it so if the user presses the buttons in an order for example : 9,2 and 3 in that order does an action and performs a Segue but if they have any other combination it does a different action

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: im new to swift and i dont really know what to try... ive searched the internet quite a bit but cannot find anything

Comment: Edit your question with a bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve and I'll try to give you some advice.

Comment: I just edited it if you could take a look it would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Try vacawama's solution. It'll do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property `var presses = [Int]()`.  Give your buttons unique `tag`s.  Wire all of your buttons to a single `@IBAction func buttonPressed(_:)` function.  When a button is pressed, `append` its `tag` to `presses`.  If `presses.count == 3`, compare your `presses` array to arrays which represent the desired orders.

```
var presses = [Int]()

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    presses.append(sender.tag)
    if presses.count == 3 {
        switch presses {
        case [9, 2, 3]:
            // play a sound

            // perform segue to next viewController
        default:
            // play "wrong" sound
        }

        // reset presses for the next 3 presses
        presses = []

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi so i tried it and for now used a print message but nothing gets printed in console no matter what combination

Comment: Time for some debugging.  Are you even getting to `buttonPressed(_:)`.  Make sure you've hooked each of your buttons to that `@IBAction`.

Comment: ah sorry i did not connect all of them thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an array and when user tap on button append button name or button tag on it. when user press 3rd button check an array is in particular order. If it matches then do some action else do another action. Array comparison looked something like this

```
 if arrMatch == [1,2,3] {
      print("do some action")
    } else {
      print("do another action")
    }
```